# IE9 input text box cursor stops flashing after Tab focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-9

An ASP.NET (4.0) enterprise Web application is being developed for my company, by an outside party.  When using Internet Explorer 9, pressing the TAB key to focus the next text box causes the text cursor to show once, and then stops blinking.  Is this an IE9 bug?  THe developer claims it is, and I can't find any obvious cause.

### Symptoms:

- Tabbing into a text box causes the blinking text cursor to stop rendering
- Clicking into a text box does not cause this problem
- This happens in IE9, but not earlier versions
- Moving the mouse pointer over another text box causes one frame of the text cursor animation to render
- Rapidly moving the mouse pointer over many text boxes causes the cursor to render somewhat smoothly, so the animation logic is still running
- This problem does not manifest when I turn off styles in the developer features
- There is no CSS directly affecting the text cursor
- There appears to be no JavaScript triggered by mouse-over events

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: I can corroborate that ie9 has some sort of bug: this error occured shortly after installing ie9 on Vista on that computer (mine).

Comment: Good to know this affects others!